# Not able to access embedded nlog config file?

Tags: c#, reflection, nlog, system.reflection

```
system.Reflection.Assembly assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            System.IO.Stream inputStream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(assembly.GetType().Namespace + "Manager.NLog.config");
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(inputStream))
            {
                string result = reader.ReadToEnd();

            }
```

getting null error as input stream ? I added the config file under the project folder.

Answer (score 4):

If you added the `Manager.NLog.config` file to the project root folder and your project is called `Foo` then the correct key under which the file will be embedded is: `Foo.Manager.NLog.config`.

In your example you seem to be using the `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly` method but have you verified that the assembly returned by this method is actually the assembly containing the `Manager.NLog.config` file?

Also note that `assembly.GetType().Namespace` will always return `System.Reflection` so your code looks like this:

```
var inputStream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("System.ReflectionManager.NLog.config");
```

and I very highly doubt that this key is correct.

So you may try something along the lines of:

```
var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
var key = assembly.GetName().Name + ".Manager.NLog.config";
using (var inputStream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(key))
using (var reader = new StreamReader(inputStream))
{
    var result = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Comment: @judithnisha, OK, then rename it, it's obvious. I will update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This code will work no matter where you put the config file in your project structure. Make sure you set Build Action to "Embedded Resource" as I'm sure you've already done.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

var exe = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
string resourceName = exe.GetManifestResourceNames()
                         .FirstOrDefault(s => s.IndexOf("NLog.config", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > -1);
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(resourceName))
{
  using (var xml = new StreamReader(exe.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName)))
  {
    string xmlConfig = xml.ReadToEnd();
    if (!File.Exists("NLog.config"))
    {
      // Do something with the log file, like write it out to the root directory.
      File.WriteAllText("NLog.config", xmlConfig);
    }
  }
}
```